# Как в canvas дать пикселю рандомный цвет?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, canvas

Всем привет! Знаю вопрос глупый, но все же: как дать каждому пикселю canvas случайный цвет? Вроде бы все просто, но есть одно НО.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

for (var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
   for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = getRandRGB();
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Вместо того, чтобы создать квадратики случайно цвета на всем canvas он делает это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Закрашивается только верхняя часть холста)

Comment: В чем проблема? Ваш алгоритм делает именно то, что вы хотите - дает пикселям рандомный цвет. Или ключевой вопрос в том, почему не весь холст закрашен?

Comment: Я не изучал канву, но по логике - нужно красить не x и y, а x[i] и y[i]

Comment: @P.Ilyin вот именно: почему не весь.

Comment: @user190134 Так красятся не x и y, красятся квадратики, находящиеся в позиции с координатами x и y.

Comment: Как вы создаёте ctx? Приведите кусок кода, в котором это происходит.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас ширина и высота канваса прописаны в стилях, а надо именно в атрибутах

Comment: если размеры `canvas` указаны в теге тогда проблема в функции `getRandomRGB()` так как она скорее всего генерирует не уникальные рандомные значения, тоесть один квадрат закрашивается несколько раз одним и тем же цветом

Comment: покажите код функции `getRandRGB()`

Comment: ой нет извиняюсь если бы не уникальные генерировала то весь канвас был бы закрашен